# Solving mathematical optimization problems with nonnegative, non-analytical objective functions

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization

I am studying a kind of nonlinear mathematical optimization problems where the objective functions are guaranteed to be nonnegative. In addition, the objective function is non-analytical; in fact, it is in the form of a C routine. The C routine needs to be treated as a blackbox as I don't access to its source.

As a total beginner in the operation research field and due to the vast literature in the field of mathematical optimization, I would like to ask which category of optimization problems I should look at to  solve my problem? Is there any field like "nonnegative programming"?

Comment: Nonnegativity generally doesn't help in numerical optimization, because any well-posed minimization problem can be made nonnegative simply by adding a constant. So let's forget about that and look at the other characteristics of your problem. In particular, if you can't evaluate the derivatives of the objective function, you'll have to resort to [derivative-free optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative-free_optimization).

Comment: How would you add a constant to make an objective function nonnegative? Most of the time you have prior knowledge of the function's minimum, so it is is unclear what constant you mean to add?

Comment: What else do you know about the objective? Is it continuous, at least? Convex?

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo  Not a lot.  It is a black-box, floating-point program.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that from an optimization perspective, nonnegative functions don't look much different from arbitrary bounded-from-below functions. Consider the functions $f(x)=(x-1)^2+1$ and $g(x)=(x-1)^2-1$. Only the former is nonnegative, but I can make them both nonnegative by adding any sufficiently large constant, say $1000$, and it doesn't change the location of the minimum.